# Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot installation mess up

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, multi-boot

I've been trying to set up Ubuntu 14.04LTS and Windows 8 for quite some time now; several months. I've had over four failed attempts. I finally gave up and worked on Ubuntu in VMware from inside Windows. But now I feel I really need a dual-boot and a VM is just not sufficient.

OK. So the REAL MESS is... In a frantic effort to get a dual-boot set up, I messed up the hard disk partitions really badly. Also, I tried with Fedora 20 on reading somewhere that it supports UEFI and SecureBoot; but even that failed.

**So my current configurations and setups that I have are as follows:**

***Boot Configuration Details:***

When I switch on my PC, I get the Metro-UI Windows bootloader. However, on restart, I am presented with a non-Metro-UI OS selection menu with OS selection options, viz. Windows 8 and Fedora 20. On selecting Fedora, an error is presented. Windows boots fine.

EasyBCD, however, shows a strange set of boot entries...

[image]

[image]

***Hard disk partitions:***

AOMEI partition manager shows a scarily long set of partitions...

[image: AOMEI partition manager screenshot]

Please help me understand the exact purpose of each of the drives shown in AOMEI so that I may delete unnecessarily created drives when I installed Fedora 20. Here is what I understood, kindly correct me if I am wrong...

- WINRE_DRV is a windows recovery system drive and shouldn't be touched.
- SYSTEM_DRV is a system drive (no idea what for) and shouldnt be touched.
- LRS_ESP is a system drive (no idea what for) and shouldnt be touched.
- FS:Other, Capacoty:128MB, Flag:GPT/MSR ... is unknown
- Windows8_OS is my C:\ drive
- Personal Data is my data drive
- FS:Other, Capacoty:1MB, Flag:GPT ... is unknown
- J: drive ...is unknown and surprisingly its FS is ext4 but Windows can access it. :P
- FS: Other, Capacity: 19GB, ...probably my Fedora20 installation
- F: (with FS FAT12)... unknown (what is fat12???)
- H: EFISECTOR is unknown
- D: LENOVO contains drivers and some other stuff
- PBR_DRV ...contains a flag of WRE, but I already have a recovery drive! So even this is unknown.

And if I look at "Computer" in Windows Explorer, it shows some unexplained drives of a few MBs. There are also some more partitions that are not visible to Windows, probably because they were in ext4 when I had attempted the Fedora 20 setup. You can see these 'invisible' drives in the AOMEI screenshot above.

[image]

Now I wish to clean up all this mess and do a clean Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot.

Also, two side questions...

First, should I install 15.04 or 14.04LTS given my situation? I read on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) that dual booting is a breeze with 15.04. But the "LTS" will be missed and I would prefer LTS.

Second, should I upgrade to Windows 8.1? Will upgrading later on after a (hopeful) dual-boot setup mess up my configs again?

Comment: You posted Screenshot_4 twice, leaving out the Windows Explorer screenshot.

Comment: @G-Man edited it... :P :P And once again, i cannot add more than 2 links.. :P

Comment: We normally don't do this, but ...  post the fourth URL in a comment here, and I'll put it in.

Comment: Thanks a lot @G-Man...
Here's the link to the Windows Explorer screenshot..
http://s21.postimg.org/9uu8tgbvb/Screenshot_5.png

Comment: MercuryX: Done.

Comment: You're welcome.  I was going to say that you would probably be able to edit the question as long as you didn't touch the links, but I wasn't sure.  I'm glad to see that you tried it anyway, and that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your two questions, I would go for 15.04. It's stable enough.

I don't think upgrading Windows will mess up boot records, no matter if they're MBR or EFI.

About the clean install, I suggest a restore of Windows because I can see you have a backup partition `LENOVO`. Afterwards, you should try to install Ubuntu in EFI mode.

Comment: okay. So you so that LTS updates are not worth it? It is to be noted that I am into a lot of coding and programming.

Comment: In general LTS updates are worth it, however 15.04 has a lot of new programming applications in the default repos that are not in the repos for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, so in your case you should consider at least trying the Ubuntu 15.04 live DVD/USB. Then you can see the difference and decide  if it's worth it.